# on concatenating two String s1 and s2, produced output String s3 will create in heap or constant pool in java?

Tags: java, string

```
String S1="He";
String S2="llow";
String S3="Hellow";
String S4="He"+"llow";
String S5=S1+S2;
System.out.println(S3==S4); // prints true
System.out.println(S5==S3); // prints false
System.out.println(S5==S4); // prints false
```

why `S5` is not referring object from constant pool?
since `S3` and `S4` are in pool thats why giving true on `S3==S4` 
but in case of `S5==S3` & `S5==S4` result is false,means S5 is not in pool.

Comment: You might need this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13450392/why-are-equal-java-strings-taking-the-same-address/13450446#13450446

Answer (score 5):

The strings `s1` through `s4` are all *compile time* constants.

The compiler calculates `"He" + "llow"` during compile time, and consults the string pool as to whether the result is already there, and puts it there if it doesn't.

But the calculation of `s1 + s2` is not done in compile time, and therefore its result is not interned. Why? Because in theory, another thread could change the value of `s1` or `s2` so by the time we get to this instruction in the code, it may set `s2` to `"foo"`, so the result becomes `"Hefoo"`.

You, as the author, may know that no thread will be doing that and that these are local variables anyway, but the compiler doesn't.

If you change your definitions to:

```
    final String s1="He";
    final String s2="llow";
    final String s3="Hellow";
    final String s4="He"+"llow";
    final String s5=s1+s2;
```

Then indeed, the result of `s5 == s3` will be `true`! Why? Because the `final` keyword lets the compiler know that these strings are not going to be replaced, they are the *final* value of these variables. So it can calculate it in compile time and take the result that is already in the pool.

Answer (score 2):

from JLS

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5

> Strings computed by constant expressions (§15.28) are computed at
>   compile time and then treated as if they were literals.
>
> Strings computed by concatenation at run time are newly created and
>   therefore distinct.

In the case of String S4, you're doing **compile time concatenation**,

`String S4="He"+"llow";`
therefore, it refers to the same object as S3

however , `S1+S2`  is a concatenation at run time , therefore , it refers to separate String object than S3 even though `S1 + S2` and `S3` are **meaningfully equivalent** . 
 i.e `(S1+S2).equals(S3)` would return true

you can put a String in pool using `intern` method

Comment: I got a point S5 resolve at run time.I am adding in my question--- if in this code we add same s6=s1+s2;then what will be output on s5==s6 and why?

Comment: it wud be false since they both are resolved at run time .Strings resolved at run time are created as distinct objects on heap . Only literal Strings and literal String concatenation at compile time can be placed in String pool

Answer (score 2):

Since in `String S4="He"+"llow";` Object create in pool and this is compile time constant same as `S3="Hellow";` both are same object in pool but `S5` created in heap at run time.

Answer (score 0):

String literals that are concatenated are entered into the String pool.  A String resulting from concatenation of variables however is not.  That is why S3 is equal to S4 but not S5. They are not referring to the same object.  However, (although I haven't tested this out) S5.equals(S4) should return true.

Comment: since S3 and S4 also referring the same object from constant pool.as you told s5 will refer from pool means S5 will also refer the same object,then why s5==s4 & s5==s3 giving false.

Comment: @dubey-theHarcortians S5 does not refer from the pool because S5 is created at runtime as a new String, based on the variables S3 and S4, which are literal values and therefore entered in to the pool at compile time.

Comment: thanks.got a point S5 resolve at run time.I am adding in my question--- if in this code we add same s6=s1+s2;then what will be output on s5==s6 and why?

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(S3==S4);//true
```

Because `S4 = "He"+"llow";` is optimised by the compiler and lead to the same string as "Hellow" which is **shared** with `S3`, hence S4 and S3 have the same reference.

```
System.out.println(S5==S3);//false
```

Because `S5` and S3 are 2 distinct objects with different references.

```
System.out.println(S5==S4);//false
```

Same thing as before.

When you compare objects, you usually want to compare the content (with `equals()` and not the address/reference (with `==`).

Answer (score 0):

In general the compiler interns constant strings - even the ones created by a concatenation. That is why `S3` and `S4` are the same object.

`S5` however is evaluated at runtime, that is why it creates a new object, distinct (but equal to) `S4`. If you put it into the string pool yourself, you will again get the same object as `S4`, so `S5.intern() == S4` would be true.

Note that `S5` not being the same as `S4` is not guaranteed. A more optimizing compiler could put it into the string pool at compile time.

Comment: if in this code we add same s6=s1+s2;then what will be output on s5==s6 and why?

Comment: since s1+s2 would be evaluated twice, once for s5 and once for s6, s5==s6 would return false. But as said, don't rely on that. A clever compiler could optimize the second evaluation away.

Answer (score -1):

compare string in java use equals

in a java objects == compare memory adresses

String S5=S1+S2;

S1+S2 return new string object

some objet have distinct memory adress
you may compare use equals

System.out.println(S5.equals(S4));

if you concat many string objects use StringBuilder
they fowing fasted and use minimum memory